# yii multiple listBox Selected values on top

Tags: php, yii

Is there any way to show all the multiple selected values on the top. 
eg. if the list contains 1 to 10 and selected values are 4,8 then the listbox should have values like 4,8,1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10

Comment: When the user select it should be on top? if so you'll have to use JS, or it's on the display of a saved value, if it so just sort prior to the exhibition

Comment: You need to provide us the way you populate your select.

Comment: echo $form->labelEx($model,'Stores'); 
echo CHtml::listBox('listname',$selectedlist,$alllist,array('multiple' => 'multiple'));

Comment: Thanks, see my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the two common ways to list data for selects.

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('public', $model, array('0' => 'Private', '1' => 'Public'));

echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'developers_id', CHtml::listData(Developers::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'email') , array('prompt'=>'Select'));
```

The first one uses an array, and you can define, relocate your array keys based on user preference.

On second, probably introducing a Criteria in the findAll() call that will order the user chosen values first, it will do the job.

**Update**

You could go something like:

```
echo CHtml::listBox('listname',$selectedlist,array_intersect_key($alllist,array_flip($selectedlist))+$alllist,array('multiple' => 'multiple'));
```

in examples:

```
$selectedlist=array(3,5);
$alllist=array(1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five');

$a=array_intersect_key($alllist,array_flip($selectedlist))+$alllist;
print_r($a);

Array ( [3] => three [5] => five [1] => one [2] => two [4] => four )
```

See the code in action http://ideone.com/6BDxQ